# JPA2: @Min constraint for float

Tags: java, jpa, entity

Is it possible to apply @Min constraint to a float type?

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Stock
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Min(0.1)
    private float count;
}
```

Long type is required in @Min annotation so is there any other way how to achieve the same?

Comment: Please express your concern "After some time I found it that @DecimalMin behaves strange for float type. According to documentation you have to use BigDecimal. See http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/bean-validation-api/1.0/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html" to the discussion of the answer and undo the accepted mark on the answer if it's wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@DecimalMax

The value of the field or property must be a decimal value lower than or equal to the number in the value element.

```
@DecimalMax("30.00")
BigDecimal discount;
```

@DecimalMin

The value of the field or property must be a decimal value greater than or equal to the number in the value element.

```
@DecimalMin("5.00")
BigDecimal discount;
```

@Digits

The value of the field or property must be a number within a specified range. The integer element specifies the maximum integral digits for the number, and the fraction element specifies the maximum fractional digits for the number.

```
@Digits(integer=6, fraction=2)
BigDecimal
```

Comment: "Note that double and float are not supported due to rounding errors (some providers might provide some approximative support)."
https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMax.html